# How to break in interactive mode on an exception to debug a Python script?

Tags: python, debugging

I would like to debug a Python package, let say it is Sphinx.

when I do `sphinx-build` everything works utile a point I have an exception. Instead of the Traceback I would like to start an interactive session from there in which I can debug my code.

Is that possible?

For instance I am looking for something like:

```
$ python-debug sphinx-build arg args 
... 
...
Traceback (oops)
...
>>> print("Oh yeah, now we can play...")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps pdb might be of use to you. Simply invoke it like so where you want to break into the debugger:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

For more details please see the pdb documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Edit: Perhaps more relevant to your question: pdb can be invoked on the command-line like so: `python3 -m pdb myscript.py`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a write access to the source code. I need to wrap it from the command line as showed

Comment: So in my example I should do `$ python3 -m pdb /usr/local/bin/sphinx-build .`. Unfortunately I cannot run my script. With `(Pdb) run` it stops at `__requires__ = 'Sphinx'

Comment: Does it stop entirely? Can you step through it by typing "step" or "next"?

Comment: Well, I found that I should use `continue` and not `run`

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you to  figure out where to place a debugger:

- Check the line number in the Traceback of the module.
- Then open the module in any of the text editor by going into the module location.
- Keep the debugger before that line.

If your are using python3.7 Then you can simply call this function `breakpoint()` or you can also do this by using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.